# how I can get data by entering primary key of my specific database record

Tags: c#, datatable, textbox

"how I can get data by entering primary key of my specific database record issue is that when I enter CustomerID in loadByCustomerIDTextBox it returns record based on row index not by the primary key I gave throug textbox"

I have tried a lot but not solved plaese help

```
    private void loadCustomerInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        int customerId = Convert.ToInt16(loadByCustomerIDTextBox.Text);
        DataTable dtCustomerDetails = GetCustomerDetailsByCustomerID();

        DataRow row = dtCustomerDetails.Rows[customerId];

        //load data into
        customerIDTextBox.Text = row["CustomerID"].ToString();
        editCustomerNameTextBox.Text = row["CustomerName"].ToString();
        editCustomerFatherNameTextBox.Text = row["FatherName"].ToString();

    }
```

Comment: sorry the correct line code of imput parameter is " cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerID", loadByCustomerIDTextBox.Text); "

Comment: It would also help if you could post your storedprocedure code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
DataRow row = dtCustomerDetails.Rows[customerId];
```

Do this

```
var dataRow=dtCustomerDetails.Select("Id=" + yourId);
```

It will get you the record with Primary key of whatever you want.

Note: Verify your `PK column` and then use this within select.

Hope it helps!

Comment: what is the name of your primary key column?

Comment: CustomerID is the PK column

Comment: Then do this `var dataRow=dtCustomerDetails.Select("CustomerID =" + yourId);`